# Waiting for a background network task to finish and return the response to mainActivity without blocking the UI

Tags: java, android

Currently I have an async task that contacts a REST api endpoint and gets the result from it.
The issue is that by using get() the UI thread is blocked, I would like to avoid this, how do I achieve it.

Here's the code I'm using

```
    public static class checkStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response = null;
            String token = strings[0];
            String id = strings[1];
            String pass = strings[2];
            String guid = strings[3];

            try {
                String url = "http://teststatus.com/checkStatus";
                URL apiUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                connection.setRequestProperty("id", id);

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                object.put("id", id);
                object.put("pass", pass);
                object.put("guid", guid);


                byte[] out = String.valueOf(object).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
                stream.write(out);

                int status = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (status == 200 || status == 202) {
                    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    response = stringBuilder.toString();

                }
                if (status != 200) {
                    response = connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                return null;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

and I call it in another activity like this

```
statuses.checkStatus checkStatus = new statuses.checkStatus();
String result = checkStatus.execute(token, id, pass, guid).get();
```

How would I best achieve it ? I need the in checkStatus to finish before the application continues to the next part of the code, but I don't want it to block the UI. How do I write some kind of a loop to check whether the checkStatus has returned a result without it blocking the UI thread ? It doesn't have to be an async task, tried making an executor, still have to use get in order to get the result.

Comment: If code looks like that it can't be non-blocking because it needs to return a result once the method call finishes or the code could not continue. The code can't jump away to anything else in the meantime while in that line. You'll need to supply a disconnected piece of code to a callback that runs once the task is done. For AsyncTask that would be done by overriding the post execute method `protected void onPostExecute(String s) { .. }`. Or you overhaul that code, use a nice http library and kotlin coroutines, AsyncTask is deprecated and I wouldn't use HttpURLConnection unless forced to

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` has method  [`onPostExecute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Result)). It's exactly what you wants as it runs on the UI thread after the main logic of the AsyncTask completed: